# Android: Continuing executing from the location where intent was started after finish()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am coding an Android application that displays a RecyclerView with some elements and some CRUD operations. One thing I am trying to do is to update an existing element from my RecyclerView, and for that I open a new activity where I fill some textboxes and update in a database. After I finish() the update activity, the program returns to the previous one, but not before not executing any code that remained in the method I started the intent in the first place.

Here is the code:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String planeAsString = gson.toJson(plane);
intent1.putExtra("PlaneString", planeAsString);
context.startActivity(intent1);

Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(v, "Element was updated", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setDuration(2000);
adapter.onIorUItem();
snackbar1.show();

break;
```

What should I do to be able to execute the code after the

```
context.startActivity(intent1);
```

line, after I finish the started activity. The code purpose is to show a snackbar and to call a method from the RecyclerView's adapter, so I can refresh the list. The following code is located in a class named PlaneHolder, which isn't an activity or fragment, the hierarchy of the calls being the next:

MainActivity -> FragmentOfMainActivity (here the recyclerView is located) -> PlaneAdapter -> PlaneHolder -> UpdateActivity (the activity where I update, and from where I want to return to PlaneHolder after I finish it).

Comment: You need [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Use `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult()` in the activity with the snackbar. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `startActivity()`, the new `Activity` isn't started right away. This is just a request to the Android framework to start the new `Activity`. Your code continues to run to completion before anything will happen. Android can't start the new `Activity` until your method completes and control is returned to the Android framework. That means your `Snackbar` is shown immediately before Android starts the new `Activity`. You probably just don't see it because it happens underneath the new `Activity`. Add logging or set a breakpoint and you will see this.

To fix this, use the solution suggested by @denvercoder9: instead of `startActivity()` use `startActivityForResult()` and show your `Snackbar` in `onActivityResult()`.